# Block Size and inode size in a filesystem

Tags: filesystems

I am going through the book , "Practical Filesystem design " by "Dominic Giampaolo" .

The two important concepts are

1. Block : The smallest readable or writable unit of memory for a filesystem .
2. Inode : Inode , is , an area, which stores the data about a file , stores the data about where the blocks composing  a file are stored .

The author states about the simplicity introduced by storing  a few block addresses directly in i-node . Then he mentions about tradeoff that is faced between "the size of the i-node" and how much data the i-node map .

As such he mentions that the size of the i-node works best when it is an even divisor of the block size  .

How to reason out the above statement ? Any calculations to support this ?

Answer (score 1):

Since all read/write operations operate at the block-level, then having your inodes block-aligned and occupying entire blocks ensures that your reads/writes are not wasteful.
If a block is 4096 bytes, but an inode is just 4000 bytes, then either:
1. our inodes are block-aligned: we're not very efficient since we always waste 96 bytes of every block.
2. our inodes are not block-aligned: we're not very efficient since when we want to read an inode, we often need to read two blocks - and none of them will be 100% occupied by inode data.

We remain efficient when:
1. The size of an inode equals to the size of a block (1:1 ratio)
2. The size of an inode is an exact multiple of the size of a block (1:n ratio)
3. The size of a block is an exact multiple of the size of an inode  (n:1 ratio)